# loaction of text inside Div tag is changing

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Here is link to website: https://www.ohorse.com/stables/

I want to extract the address from every div as circled in the screenshot below:

[image: Circled addresses]

Write the following code

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import NavigableString, Tag

url = 'https://www.ohorse.com/stables/'

resp = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

all_divs = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'contentright')

for div in all_divs:
    # print(div.find('a', class_ = 'listing').get('href'))
    sub_divs = div.findAll('div', class_ = 'listing_content')

    for s_div in sub_divs:
        add = list(s_div.children)[0]
        add2 = list(s_div.children)[2]

        print(add)
        print(add2)
```

And got this output:

[image: The output]

As one the very first line I got a image tag because in first div there is Facebook link is given instead of address and it do not return the address.

second with this I got some tags how I can I apply condition on tag that if list have any tag so I can pass it.

I just want a solution so I can extract address of every in standard form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.findAll('div', class_='listing_content')
    for tar in target:
        tar = list(tar.strings)[:4]
        print(list(dict.fromkeys(tar)))


main("https://www.ohorse.com/stables/")
```

Output:

```
["Visit Houghton College Equestrian Center's Facebook Page", '9823 School Farm Rd', 'Houghton, NY 14744', '(585) 567-8142']
['HC80 Box 16', 'Burwell, NE 68823', '(308) 346-5530']
['1500 Kings Gap Road', 'Pine Mountain, GA 31811', '(229) 886-1709']
['6280 Taylor Ranch Loop', 'Kaufman, TX 75142', '(972) 467-4053']
['28424 Hegar Rd', 'Hockley, TX 77447', '(281) 702-2048']
['28424 Hegar Rd', 'Hockley, TX 77447', '(936) 931-1188']
['1409 US Hwy 59', 'Garvin, MN 56132', '(507) 629-4401']
['1911 De La Vina St', 'Santa Barbara, CA 93101', '(805) 448-4896']
['Shawnee, KS 66216', '(913) 963-8212', 'brian@3sevensranch.com']
['11127 Orcas Ave', 'Lake View Terrace, CA 91342', '(818) 899-9221']
```

Comment: αмєяιcαηThanks a alot and it looks perfect But by using this approach I got an other issue because there are multiple pages through which I am crawling. And some of divs don't have address or missing some values so they return some other text and flow is disturb due to that. I am looking for some standard solution if you can help. There are many other fields to scrape and I have done with that just stuck in addresses let me share complete code for addresses only.